# How to copy vector<unique_ptr<T>> to independent vector<T*>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec1` where T is an abstract type. I'd like to create `std::vector<T*> vec2` where objects pointed by pointers from 2nd vector are copy of objects pointed by pointers of 1st vector.

So for example: `*(vec1[0]) == *(vec2[0])` and `vec1[0].get() != vec2[0]` ... etc...

How to do that?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You do not know how to get underlying pointer from `unique_ptr`? Or something else?

Comment: @SergeyA. I know hot to get raw pointer from `std::unique_ptr` (`get() ` method). But if I push it to vec2 then vec2 will not be independent of vec1. Pointers from vec1 will point to the same place in memory as pointers from vec2. I need copy of objects.

Comment: Why?​​​​​​​​​​​ This is a huge code smell. C API taking `T**` and ownership? :(

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Yes, I know that it's awful but I need this "hack" (in ut test).

Comment: Bet you don't really :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `std::transform`

```
std::vector<T*> vec2;
vec2.reserve(vec1.size()); // optimization to avoid reallocations, it isn't necessary, and without it the code still works correctly
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2), [](const std::unique_ptr<T>& p){ return YourCloneFunction(*p); }
```

One way to write a clone function is to make all your descendant classes have defined virtual `clone` function, which is abstract in `T`. The code of such method is simple, but needs to be defined for every `Derived` class.

```
class T
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~T(){}
};

class Derived : public T
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const override {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new Derived(*this));
    }
};
```

With this, the code becomes

```
std::vector<T*> vec2;
vec2.reserve(vec1.size()); // optimization to avoid reallocations, it isn't necessary, and without it the code still works correctly
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2), [](const std::unique_ptr<T>& p){ return p->clone().release(); }
```

Note that we have `vec2` raw pointers pointing to objects not owned by any smart pointer. This is bad, unless you're passing `vec2` into legacy function that takes ownership of these pointers.

Otherwise if you want only a `std::vector<T*>` view of the copies, clone into an intermediate `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, and then copy result of `.get()` on each instance to `std::vector<T*>`

Comment: as it is a copy, you should show the good behavior to call reserve of the proper size before the transform

Comment: why are you caving to this demand? There is really no reason to call `reserve` here.

Comment: @milleniumbug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The manual way:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vec1;
std::vector<T*> vec2;
vec2.reserve(vec1.size()); // optimization to avoid reallocations

for (const auto& e : vec1) {
    vec2.push_back(e->clone());
}
```

with `virtual T* T::clone() const`

Comment: as it is a copy, you should show the good behavior to call reserve of the proper size before the loop

Comment: @galop1n, no real need.

Comment: "*T is an abstract type*", which means you can't construct new instances of `T` itself.

Comment: @SergeyA: No need, but completely appropriate.